# Get the time sequence in Unix?

Tags: unix-philosophy

Actually I expect the output like

from current timestamp to 10s+current timestamp

ex:

```
11:49:01
11:49:02
11:49:03
.....
11:49:10
```

But this output must be  coming in banner output.

*Hint:*
I am able to get the first set of sequence using the below script:

```
while [ 1 ]; do
    echo $(date +%H:"$(( `date +%M`+1))":%S)
    sleep 1
done
```

I want to know how to get the above script output using banner?

Comment: the time sequence is working perfectly, but I wanna concate the output with banner command?

Comment: can you pls tell me what is wrong with this script?

Comment: $ repeat 1000 sh -c '( clear ; date +" %H.%M.%S" | xargs banner ; sleep 1)'

Answer (score 1):

- just use `date -d+10s` to get 10 seconds ahead. (by the way, you mention 10 seconds in question and use +1 minute in your code)
- next use `banner` or `printerbanner`

  ```
  ...
  banner $(date -d '+10 seconds' '+%T') # if banner exist, or
  printbanner $(date -d '+10 seconds' '+%T') # ubuntu
  ...
  ```